# Is there any way to get strings enclosed between double quotes using grep ? The string can be anything but it should be enclosed between quotes

Tags: awk, grep

How do I grep all the strings enclosed between double quotes in a .c file.
There are lots of .c files and only some of them have string constants. I want to get all the strings, basically, all those lines enclosed between double quotes.

Comment: Are you hoping to accurately handle strings that contain quotes?  (eg, `"ab\"cde"`)

Comment: This isn't possible to do robustly without writing a parser for the C language but maybe we can help you do something for a specific subset of the language that you actually have in your files. If that's what you want then please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input that shows the worst-case text you need to parse to extract strings from and the expected output given that input. Make sure to at least include newlines and escaped quotes within strings, strings within comments, unmatched quotes within comments, etc. if those can exist in your real files.

Comment: grep is really the wrong tool if you hope to handle all the corner cases (imbedded quotes, quotes in comments, quotes in character literals, etc.) I'd suggest looking at flex or some other tool for doing lexical analysis.